# Slow output of pymongo.cursor for geosearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, polygon

I perform a geosearch over one collection full of polygons. The query itself is pretty fast, but it takes over 3 minutes to get the results. I need a solution to speed up the output of the polygonnames.

I tried to include only the name, exclude the geometry and doesn't specify something at all, but all with the same effect.

Output:

```
0:00:00.000061
Result of Query
<class 'pymongo.cursor.Cursor'>
{'_id': ObjectId('5e70ab3b160bdb5ebde5da7f'), 'name': 'Hessen'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5e70ab65160bdb5ebde5e0d4'), 'name': 'Hessen/Rheingau'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5e70ab7a160bdb5ebde5e38e'), 'name': 'Hessen'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5e70b707faa4a158f866f6fb'), 'name': 'Frankfurt am Main'}
0:03:11.020437
```

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
from datetime import datetime

client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['GEO']
geo_collection = db['polygons']

starttime = datetime.now()
search_results = geo_collection.find({"geometry":
                 {"$geoIntersects":
                     {"$geometry":{ "type" : "Point",
                          "coordinates" :  [8.636274, 50.145938]}
                      }
                  }
             },{"geometry":0})

endtime = datetime.now()
print(endtime-starttime)

print("Result of Query")
print(type(search_results))
for result in search_results:
    print(result)

endtime = datetime.now()
print(endtime-starttime)
```

```
> db.polygons.explain().find({"geometry":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{ "type" : "Point","coordinates":[8.636274, 50.145938]}}}},{"name":1})
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "GEO.polygons",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "geometry" : {
                "$geoIntersects" : {
                    "$geometry" : {
                        "type" : "Point",
                        "coordinates" : [
                            8.636274,
                            50.145938
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "queryHash" : "D3B4DDC2",
        "planCacheKey" : "45C3B08C",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
            "transformBy" : {
                "name" : 1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "geometry" : {
                        "$geoIntersects" : {
                            "$geometry" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                    8.636274,
                                    50.145938
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "DTO-MB-007.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.2.3",
        "gitVersion" : "6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have a 2d index on that data?  This query is a collection scan, so every document in the collection is being loaded from disk and examined.  The time you are reporting first is just how long it took to set up the cursor, and maybe get the first batch.  The driver automatically makes as many calls as necessary to get additional batches.

Comment: The Data in mogo looks like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e70ab35160bdb5ebde5d554"), "name" : "Monaco", "geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 7.414266, 43.727287 ], [ 7.417669, 43.724243 ],... 
] ] } }

and i added the index with: db.polygons.createIndex({"geometry.coordinates":"2d"})

but it doesn't speedup the query

Answer (score 0):

A "2d" index supports legacy long/lat coordinate pairs, not GeoJSON objects like Polygon.

The [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-indexes) does have support for these.  The `geometry` field appears to be a properly formatted GeoJSON object, so you should be able to create an index like:

```
db.polygons.createIndex({"geometry":"2dsphere"})
```

This index should support the noted query.

Comment: The Index doesn't work, any idea?



> db.polygons.createIndex({geometry:"2dsphere"})
{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5e70ab77160bdb5ebde5e2b1'), name: \"Emirat Abu Dhabi\", geometry: { type: \"MultiPolygon\", coordinates: [ [ [ [ 54.478299693, 24.411246705 ],